# No network connection on Ubuntu VM with NAT and static IP

Tags: 14.04, networking

I set up an Ubuntu VM with static IP address but it cannot connect to the internet or ping the DNS server (8.8.8.8).
`ifconfig` output:

[image]

How can I fix this? The network adapters are: 
1: NAT
2: Host-only Adapter

Comment: please accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution, the router I was connected to used a different format of IP addresses (10.x.x.x), so the static IP I entered was invalid. Changing the IP address to this format solved the problem.